# Handling multiple database in Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database, django-mssql

I am developing a web-application in `Django` using MySQL database. Now, I need to connect to an internal SQL Server Database and update only 1 table `ClientDetails`

Here is my Database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    },
    'internal': {        
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'client_database',
        'USER': 'client',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'Database_Internal'        
    }
}
```

How do I write to the table `ClientDetails` in the 2nd Database?

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra entry to dictionary in settings.py

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
},
'client': {
    'NAME': 'client_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root'
}}
```

Write your mysql user and password of course.

Now to set a model to a database:-

```
my_object.save(using='client_data')
```

And there you have it.I recommend checking django documentation as no one's perfect, bus I'm pretty sure this should get you running.